# ripple migration issues

Tags: ripple

i had an old ripple account that has stayed untouched for a long time,  ripple advise that you need to migrate it to gatehub, this process does not work, i have tried to transfer it another wallet and it advised my pass phrase is incorrect, it can be only one of two passwords that i used for all online stuff at the time.

Is there away to re set the pass phrase i still have the walets secert key, i see some old links from 2013 -2015 on just setting up  new account with the secert key, but none of the new walets offer the option to add tge key on registration.

Cany anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the secret, you can forget about the old wallet. Use the secret in any XRP wallet that accepts a secret. Gatehub does. The old Ripple desktop wallet does. Jatchili's minimal client does.